Why are the contents of an NSScrollView aligned to the bottom instead of the top?
I'm trying to use an NSScrollView where the contents may be (vertically) smaller or taller than the window, changing dynamically at runtime. (This will later be a stack view with multiple views that can be shown/hidden at random.) When the contents are larger than the scroll view, everything works as expected; but when the contents are vertically smaller than the scroll view, they are displayed at the bottom of the scroll view instead of the top, where I would like them. This is despite the fact that I have added a constraint anchoring the top of the content (for testing: just a fixed-height NSBox embedded in an NSScrollView) to the top of its superview.
Some testing shows that the clip view's height follows the scroll view's height, and its origin stay the same; so I would assume that when I constrain the NSBox' top to the top of its superview (which is the clip view), it would show at the top, but instead it is displayed at the bottom.
This behavior is different from when I embed the NSBox in a simple NSView; when I do this, with the same constraints, the box is shown at the top.
Why is this happening, and how can I solve this?

Most NSView subclasses start at the bottom. If the contents of a view starts at the top, like NSTextView and NSTableView, then the coordinate system is flipped. See isFlipped.

Does this answer your question? Setting NSScrollView Contents to Top Left Instead of Bottom Left When Document Swapping

@Willeke Yes, I saw that, but I think they were not using autolayout. When I follow that recipe (embed my content in a flipped custom view, and that in turn in the scroll view), and constrain the custom view to its superview, the scroll view can't scroll any more, even when it gets smaller than the NSBox.

@Willeke Some more trial and error, now it works... I had to constrain the flipped view to the inner (NSBox) view, not to the superview. Now it works as expected. Do you want to post that as an answer, so I can give you credit?

I voted to close this question because it's a duplicate. If you want to give credit then upvote the answer to the linked question.

Thanks for that, but as I have explained, this is not an exact duplicate.

After some experimenting I was able to solve this problem.
One half of the answer is in Setting NSScrollView Contents to Top Left Instead of Bottom Left When Document Swapping : Inserting a custom view that returns YES to -isFlipped in the hierarchy between the clip view and the content.
I was able to solve the remaining part of the problem by changing the constraints: I had to constrain the edges of the custom view not to the container (the clip view of the NSScrollView), but rather to the inner view (in my test case, the NSBox). Two additional constraints connect the top and left edges of the custom "flip" view to the clip view.
